# Python Autograd Not working "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

Tags: python, numpy, autograd

I am trying to compute the Jacobian of this function but when I run the code below I get

> "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

```
import autograd.numpy as np
from autograd import grad, jacobian
from autograd.numpy import zeros, exp, log
from autograd.numpy.random import randn
from math import sqrt

def f(xi, x0=100, y0=100, dt=1.0, sx=1.0, sy=1.0):
    logtheta, u = xi[:4], xi[4:]
    t1, t2, t3, t4 = exp(logtheta)
    N = len(u) // 2
    xvec = zeros(N+1)
    yvec = zeros(N+1)
    xvec[0] = x0
    yvec[0] = y0
    for i in range(N):
        xvec[i+1] = max(0, xvec[i] + dt * (t1*xvec[i] - t2*xvec[i]*yvec[i]) + sqrt(dt) * sx * u[2*i])
        yvec[i+1] = max(0, yvec[i] + dt * (t4*xvec[i]*yvec[i] - t3*yvec[i]) + sqrt(dt) * sy * u[2*i+1])
    return np.concatenate((xvec[1:], yvec[1:]))

jacobian_f = jacobian(f)
N = 100
xi = np.concatenate((log(np.array([0.4, 0.005, 0.05, 0.001]), randn(N))
jacobian_f(xi)
```

Not sure why it says setting an array element with a sequence. `max(0, ...)` will return a float not a sequence?

## Traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ArrayBox'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/hy/57_f4xcx08b0ls2_nwwfjscr0000gn/T/ipykernel_41440/2535063600.py in <module>
      1 jacobian_f = jacobian(f)
----> 2 jacobian_f(xi_star)

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/autograd/wrap_util.py in nary_f(*args, **kwargs)
     18             else:
     19                 x = tuple(args[i] for i in argnum)
---> 20             return unary_operator(unary_f, x, *nary_op_args, **nary_op_kwargs)
     21         return nary_f
     22     return nary_operator

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/autograd/differential_operators.py in jacobian(fun, x)
     55     (out1, out2, ...) then the Jacobian has shape (out1, out2, ..., in1, in2, ...).
     56     """
---> 57     vjp, ans = _make_vjp(fun, x)
     58     ans_vspace = vspace(ans)
     59     jacobian_shape = ans_vspace.shape + vspace(x).shape

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/autograd/core.py in make_vjp(fun, x)
      8 def make_vjp(fun, x):
      9     start_node = VJPNode.new_root()
---> 10     end_value, end_node =  trace(start_node, fun, x)
     11     if end_node is None:
     12         def vjp(g): return vspace(x).zeros()

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/autograd/tracer.py in trace(start_node, fun, x)
      8     with trace_stack.new_trace() as t:
      9         start_box = new_box(x, t, start_node)
---> 10         end_box = fun(start_box)
     11         if isbox(end_box) and end_box._trace == start_box._trace:
     12             return end_box._value, end_box._node

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/autograd/wrap_util.py in unary_f(x)
     13                 else:
     14                     subargs = subvals(args, zip(argnum, x))
---> 15                 return fun(*subargs, **kwargs)
     16             if isinstance(argnum, int):
     17                 x = args[argnum]

/var/folders/hy/57_f4xcx08b0ls2_nwwfjscr0000gn/T/ipykernel_41440/464166274.py in f(xi, x0, y0, dt, sx, sy)
     11     yvec[0] = y0
     12     for i in range(N):
---> 13         xvec[i+1] = max(0, xvec[i] + dt * (t1*xvec[i] - t2*xvec[i]*yvec[i]) + sqrt(dt) * sx * u[2*i])
     14         yvec[i+1] = max(0, yvec[i] + dt * (t4*xvec[i]*yvec[i] - t3*yvec[i]) + sqrt(dt) * sy * u[2*i+1])
     15     return np.concatenate((xvec[1:], yvec[1:]))

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Autograd doesn't support assignment into arrays, so to use autograd you have to rewrite your code to avoid it. See [this issue on github](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/issues/177) for a bit more info.

Comment: might i suggest using pytorch instead?

Comment: @yannziselman that's a good shout. Would you be able to give me a quick example of how I could compute the jacobian in this case using Pytorch?

Comment: @yannziselman I found this post https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-compute-jacobian-matrix-in-pytorch/14968/8 and someone recommends using the function here https://gist.github.com/sbarratt/37356c46ad1350d4c30aefbd488a4faa. Do you know if this is what I am looking for?